# LINQ JOIN query return values that don't exist in one table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a `Linq to Entities` query such as this:

```
public IQueryable<Teachers> GetTeachersByKey()
{
    return from t in this.Context.Teachers
           join t2 in this.Context.Table2 on t.Teacher_K equals t2.Teacher_K
           select t;
}
```

The problem is that it also returns `Teachers_K` values that don't even exist in `Teachers` table.

How can I update the query to exclude those results?
I tried joining it Teachers into its self but that didn't do anything.

Comment: this is the syntax for an inner join, so you'll have to describe or provide your results for anyone to know what you're talking about

Comment: @Jonesy : I described it: "The problem is that it also returns Teachers_K values that don't even exist in Teachers table" Nice website name BTW

Comment: Nevermind, there was an other join somewhere else in the code, I deleted it, fixed this.